# Erro ao gravar arquivo de texto: cannot convert std::string to const char*

Tags: c++, string, arquivo

Não estou conseguindo gravar uma *string* em arquivo `.txt` em C++ (CodeBlocks).

```
// aux é um inteiro
// aux2 é uma string
// foi dado fopen no arquivo...abaixo só segue a parte com erro   

aux = x.retorne_energia();
aux2 = x.retorna_nome();
fprintf(arquivo,"%d",aux);

fputs(aux2,arquivo);
aux1 = y.retorne_energia();
aux2 = y.retorna_nome();

fprintf(arquivo,"%d %s",aux,aux2);
fclose(arquivo);
```

Como posso resolver os erros abaixo?

> error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to
>   'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int fputs(const char*, FILE*)'|
>
> error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string
>   {aka class std::basic_string}' through '...'|
>
> format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 4 has type
>   'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' [-Wformat]|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As funções [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) e [`fputs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputs/) aceitam o tipo  `const char *`, você está passando uma variável [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Use [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) para usar a variável como *C-string*:

```
// ...
fputs(aux2.c_str(), arquivo);
// ...
fprintf(arquivo,"%d %s", aux, aux2.c_str());
```

Comment: Obrigado sunstreaker, funcionou do modo que você falou.

Comment: @IagoOchoa Você tem que fazer a mesma transformação no caso do `fprintf` também.